# jquery serialize input with arrays

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization, multidimensional-array

I have a form on my site like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
 <input type="text" name="name[1][first]">
 <input type="text" name="name[2][first]">
 <input type="text" name="name[3][first]">
</form>
```

I want to simply grab all the data and send it to a webservice so have this js:

```
$fields = $('#myform').serializeArray();
```

Problem is, it creates the json with all the brackets shown in the input names so I get a parse error.

How can I use serializeArray and get proper json?

The resulting format that I would like to see is something like this:

```
{
  "name": {
    "1": {
      "first": "val1"
    },
    "2": {
      "first": "val2"
    },
    "3": {
      "first": "val3"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 10 question, 0% accepted answers.

Comment: You'll have to change the names of your inputs. The JSON serializer won't invent proper names for them.

Answer (score 16):

I made a recursive function/plugin to do exactly this:

```js
$.fn.serializeControls = function() {
  var data = {};

  function buildInputObject(arr, val) {
    if (arr.length < 1)
      return val;  
    var objkey = arr[0];
    if (objkey.slice(-1) == "]") {
      objkey = objkey.slice(0,-1);
    }  
    var result = {};
    if (arr.length == 1){
      result[objkey] = val;
    } else {
      arr.shift();
      var nestedVal = buildInputObject(arr,val);
      result[objkey] = nestedVal;
    }
    return result;
  }

  $.each(this.serializeArray(), function() {
    var val = this.value;
    var c = this.name.split("[");
    var a = buildInputObject(c, val);
    $.extend(true, data, a);
  });
  
  return data;
}

$("#output").html(JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeControls(), null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="" method="">
 <input type="text" name="name[1][first]" value="beep">
 <input type="text" name="name[1][second]" value="bloop">
 <input type="text" name="name[2][first]" value="derp">
  
 <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">  
</form>

<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

You can also call it on other selectors besides the entire `form`.  For example, calling:

`$('input[name^="name\\["]').serializeControls()`

will return an object containing only the `name` fields.  See http://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/MyWZdN for more examples.

Please note that (for now), this will not work for field names with empty brackets (for example, fields like `input name="potatoes[]"` will be ignored because a unique key cannot be extracted).

Comment: This is ace. I tried the jquery-serialize-object plugin, which didn't work, but this does. Lovely.

Comment: Hi, your code seems to not serialize properly `<select multiple>` : `var val = this.value;` only return the first selected value (tested on firefox). As this is a hack for jquery, I think this can be fixed easily with `$(this).val()` instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing this ! Should definetly be the accepted answer !

Comment: Failed for 2 dimentional array

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version of alexw code that **works for field names with empty brackets**. This allow you to manage fields with multiple values (checkboxes, select multiple).

```
$j.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var data = {};

    function buildInputObject(arr, val) {
        if (arr.length < 1) {
            return val;  
        }
        var objkey = arr[0];
        if (objkey.slice(-1) == "]") {
            objkey = objkey.slice(0,-1);
        }  
        var result = {};
        if (arr.length == 1){
            result[objkey] = val;
        } else {
            arr.shift();
            var nestedVal = buildInputObject(arr,val);
            result[objkey] = nestedVal;
        }
        return result;
    }

    function gatherMultipleValues( that ) {
        var final_array = [];
        $j.each(that.serializeArray(), function( key, field ) {
            // Copy normal fields to final array without changes
            if( field.name.indexOf('[]') < 0 ){
                final_array.push( field );
                return true; // That's it, jump to next iteration
            }

            // Remove "[]" from the field name
            var field_name = field.name.split('[]')[0];

            // Add the field value in its array of values
            var has_value = false;
            $j.each( final_array, function( final_key, final_field ){
                if( final_field.name === field_name ) {
                    has_value = true;
                    final_array[ final_key ][ 'value' ].push( field.value );
                }
            });
            // If it doesn't exist yet, create the field's array of values
            if( ! has_value ) {
                final_array.push( { 'name': field_name, 'value': [ field.value ] } );
            }
        });
        return final_array;
    }

    // Manage fields allowing multiple values first (they contain "[]" in their name)
    var final_array = gatherMultipleValues( this );

    // Then, create the object
    $j.each(final_array, function() {
        var val = this.value;
        var c = this.name.split('[');
        var a = buildInputObject(c, val);
        $j.extend(true, data, a);
    });

    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have successfully serialized the array to `$fields`, you can now walk through it and convert it into a more easily digestable result object:

```
var result = {};
for(var i in $fields) {
   var parts = $fields[i].name.split("[");
   var resultIndex = parseInt(parts[1].replace(']', ''), 10);
   result[resultIndex] = $fields[i].value; 
}
```

While `$fields` is a valid name for a global variable, I can't bare to keep silent on this matter: in JavaScript, local variables are defined with `var` keyword and they don't have dollar sign before them - dollar sign usually refers to jQuery object. As a result you can fetch the fields by invoking:

```
var fields = $('#myform').serializeArray();
```

Comment: The name of the variable makes no difference., and whether or not it's global isn't related to the question.

Comment: That was just a typo on my part when typing in the question.  It's the PHP in me coming out.

Comment: How can I get this to work when the form has other inputs as well?  When I add inputs such as: <input type="text" name="age"> I  get a js error that parts[1] is undefined.  I assume this is because it is trying to parse elements without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I used `serializeArray()` function it's solved my problem

```
 let fd = $( "input[name^='INPUT_NAME']" ).serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

the `serializeArray()` if it writes the input array.
But it saves it with name 'imputName []' The problem is extracting it.
But here I have a solution. Please check the code syntax.

```
var formArraySerializado = $("#form").serializeArray();

var imputArray = [];

$(formArraySerializado).each(function(i, field){
    
    row[field.name] = field.value;

    if (field.name.indexOf("imputArray[]") >=0){
        imputArray.push(field.value)
    }
});
```