# serializeArray with indexed input names

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form what contains a repeater field set with 4 inputs. These inputs (text + number fields) names is structured as follows: "stay[1][type-room]" with the number being changes as people add more field sets.

The end goal is to pass all the forms inputed data through Ajax to PHP.

Have been looking at using serializeArray to gather and process the data.
Here is my JQuery script i have at the moment.

JQuery

```
var stay_data = {};
$.each($('#check-availability').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
 stay_data[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

PHP Output

```
Array
(
    [check-in-date] => January 7, 2021
    [check-out-date] => January 9, 2021
    [stay[0] => Array
        (
            [num-adults] => -1
            [num-children] => 
            [num-infants] => 
            [type-room] => ANY
        )

    [stay[1] => Array
        (
            [num-adults] => 1
            [num-children] => 
            [num-infants] => 
            [type-room] => TW
        )

    [property_opt_code] => BELACSAF002??????
    [night] => 2
)
```

This output is close to what I need but I need the "stay" key values to be a array and not having it display individually.

so in the end having all the repeater fields under a single key called "stay" then bing able to get the end result as a associative array in PHP

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JS but try using `stay[][type-room]`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but have also tried that before and what happens then is that output only returns the last stay[] key

Comment: After doing some more searching I came across the following that worked for me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127227/jquery-serialize-input-with-arrays
I just changed it a bit to fit my needs.