# PHP form and serializeArray

Tags: php, jquery, forms, serialization

I have my data like this:

```
"waveOptions" => array(
            "barWidth" => 2,
            "barRadius" => 0
 ),
```

My form:

```
   <input type="number" min="0" step="1" name="waveOptions[barWidth]" value="<?php echo($options['waveOptions']['barWidth']); ?>">
   <input type="number" min="0" step="1" name="waveOptions[barRadius]" value="<?php echo($options['waveOptions']['barRadius']); ?>">
```

When I submit form I use jQuery serializeArray

```
var options = { };
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
   options[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

and I sent this to php ith JSON.stringify(options) and then save this in table with serialize($options). However when I retrieve the values with php its showing me this:

```
["waveOptions[barWidth]"]=> string(1) "x" ["waveOptions[barRadius]"]=> string(1) "y"
```

How do I format the input name

```
name="waveOptions[barWidth]"
```

so it saves this as its retrieved

```
 $options['waveOptions']['barWidth'] ?
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127227/jquery-serialize-input-with-arrays but maybe there is a better answer.

Comment: If you just want to pass those inputs in that format to PHP using JS, why not just do: `$('form').serialize();` and post that as the payload?